# asp.net dropdownlist avoid firing selectedindexchange on first keystroke

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, dropdown

I have a asp.net dropdownlist with SelectedindexChanged event wired up, which is changing some other control values based on selected value.

Say, the dropdownlist contains list of country. Now, the user opens the dropdown by clicking mouse, then user can type  In to select India and then press enter to cause "SelectedIndexChanged" to fire. Which is correct/required behaviour.

However, When user reaches this dropdownlist by pressing tab on previous control and starts typing, say I (with intention to type IN to select India), it fires SelectedIndexChanged event on first keystroke (I )causing changes and sets country as Iceland. Can we avoid this? or open dropdown on focus or first keypress. Or some other idea?

Answer (score 0):

One method you could use to counter this, although slightly obfuscated, is an `<asp:Button>` with `display: none;` on it. You'd move your dropdown events to the button's `OnClick`, and trigger that using JavaScript when your dropdown loses focus.

**jQuery**

```
$("#dropdown").focusout(function() {          //When dropdown loses focus
    var v = $(this).val();
    if (v.length) {                           //If an item is selected
        $("#btnHidden").trigger("click");     //Trigger hidden button click
    }
});
```

**ASP**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="dropdown" AutoPostBack="false">
    <asp:ListItem text="Select something..." val=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem text="Choice One" val="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem text="Choice Two" val="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="btnHidden" CssClass="hide" OnClick="btnHidden_Click"></asp:Button>
```

**C#**

```
protected void btnHidden_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Dropdown Stuff
}
```